# What is the difference between arrow and conventional function notation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var rahul = {
  name: 'Rahul',
  lastName: 'Kumar',
  yearOfBirth: 1990,
  calculateAge: function() {
    return 2018 - this.yearOfBirth;
  }
}
console.log(rahul.calculateAge());
// output : 31
var rahul = {
  name: 'Rahul',
  lastName: 'Kumar',
  yearOfBirth: 1990,
  calculateAge: () => {
    return 2018 - this.yearOfBirth;
  }
}
console.log(rahul.calculateAge());
// Output : NaN
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar arrow functions are **significantly** different from ordinary functions.

Comment: @PraveenKumar — You mean there are major differences between them that trip people up, and make code harder to maintain if you use them inappropriately?

Comment: @Quentin Kinda, yeah...

Comment: I swear finding duplicates here is way harder than it should be.

Comment: @Pointy Do you mean the scope changes?

Comment: @PraveenKumar it's not *scope*, it's the way `this` is treated, the fact that there's no `arguments` object, etc.

Comment: I am getting different outputs by using different function

Comment: @RahulKumar Yes... You don't have the option to use `this` in case of arrow functions. Right!

Comment: @PraveenKumar — Wrong.

Comment: @Quentin Sure... Thanks. Correct me for that statement. I need to improve as well. There's something related to `this` in this context. What's `this` here?

Comment: @PraveenKumar — There's a perfectly good duplicate question linked at the top of the page that explains.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry for being dumb... `:P` Gotcha... Nice one BTW...

Comment: Still not able to understand the difference in the output. BTW thanks.